Upper bound on higher order derivatives of $\frac{1}{v(t)}$
Suppose that $ v(t) >l>0$ and
$$
\vert v^{(k)}(t) \vert \leq c \frac{k!}{r^k}.
$$
Can we give an upper bound for
$$
(\frac{1}{v(t)})^{(k)}
$$
?
Attempt:
We first compute the first fourth order derivatives :
$$
(v^{-1})'= (-1)v^{-2} v' \quad \quad \quad
(v^{-1})''=  (-1)(-2)v^{-3} (v')^2 + (-1)v^{-2} v''\\
(v^{-1})''' 
= (-1)(-2)(-3) v^{-4} (v')^3 + (-1)(-2)v^{-3} 3v' v'' + (-1)v^{-2} v''' \\
(v^{-1})^{(4)} = (-1)(-2)(-3)(-4) v^{-5} (v')^4 + (-1)(-2)(-3)v^{-4} 6 (v')^2  v'' \\
+ (-1)(-2) v^{-3} ( 3 (v'')^2 + 4 v' v''') + (-1)v^{-2} v^{(4)}
$$
With observation, we find that
$$
(v^{-1})^{(n)} = \sum^n_{k=1} (-1)^k k! v^{-k-1} (a_{\mathbf{n}_{k,1}} v^{(\mathbf{n}_{k,1})} + a_{\mathbf{n}_{k,2}} v^{(\mathbf{n}_{k,2})} + \cdots + a_{\mathbf{n}_{k,A(n,k)}} v^{(\mathbf{n}_{k,A(n,k)})} )
$$
where
$\mathbf{n}_{k,i}$,$i = 1, 2 \cdots, A(n,k)$ denotes the $k$ component vector
$$
(n^{k,i}_1, n^{k,i}_2, \cdots, n^{k,i}_k),  
$$
which satisfies $ n^{k,i}_1 + n^{k,i}_2 + \cdots + n^{k,i}_k = n $.
$$
v^{(\mathbf{n}_{k,i})} = v^{(n^{k,i}_1)} v^{(n^{k,i}_2)}\cdots v^{(n^{k,i}_k)}
$$
$A(n,k)$ denotes the number of  positive integer solutions of equation
$$
x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n
$$
here notice that, for two solutions $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ $(y_1,y_2,\cdots, y_n)$ only with difference in order, we see them as the same solution and count only once, for example, $(1,1,2)$, $(1,2,1)$.
Now how can we represent the coefficients
$$
a_{\mathbf{n}_{k,i}}, \quad k=1,\cdots,n, \quad i = 1, 2,\cdots, A(n,k)
$$
and number $A(n,k)$?

yes. You can. No derivatives of positive power will ever appear in the denominator. I also believe you can write the $k$th derivative explicitly using induction.

@Medo Thank you for comment. I will try it after today's teaching work.
